# The performance of mysql fulltext depend on order of keyword

Tags: mysql, performance, full-text-search, query-performance

I am having problem with mysql fulltext search. When I change the order of keyword, the search speed changes. For example I have 4 queries, all of them return same result:

1. FAST (1s)

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM   table
   WHERE  (MATCH (column_data) AGAINST('+english* +php*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
   ```
2. SLOW (10s)

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM   table
   WHERE  MATCH (column_data) AGAINST('+php* +english*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
   ```
3. FAST (1s)

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM   table
   WHERE  MATCH (column_data) AGAINST('+php*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
   AND    (MATCH (column_data)) AGAINST('+english*' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
   ```
4. SLOW (10s)

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM   table
   WHERE  (MATCH (column_data) AGAINST('+english*' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
   AND    (MATCH (column_data) AGAINST('+php*' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
   ```

How can I optimize it?

Comment: MyISAM?  or InnoDB?  Which version of MySQL?  What is the value of the setting for min word len?

Comment: @RickJames I am using InnoDB, version 5.7. This is longtext field.

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html#fulltext-optimize

```
set GLOBAL innodb_optimize_fulltext_only=ON;
OPTIMIZE TABLE `table`;
```

Please run that, time your variations again, and report back.

If it fails to help, report a bug at bugs.mysql.com .